# Cannot create and write content in a file from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, rhel

I am creating a shell script on Linux machine. I am doing the following lines of code:

```
RESPONSE_FILE='/var/tmp/abc'
chmod 777 '/var/tmp'
chown root '/var/tmp'
touch $RESPONSE_FILE
logger "[INFO]      File created."
logger "[INFO]      Giving root permissions"
chmod 777 $RESPONSE_FILE
chown root $RESPONSE_FILE
logger "[STATUS]        Writing contents on the file."
cat > $RESPONSE_FILE <<-'EOF'
...some content...
EOF
```

The above code runs fine from a command line. But when I perform the same from a .sh script, the cat command does not write in the file and the touch command does not create a file. But the script runs successfully. When I browse to see the file its not there. Can someone please help why this is not running from .sh script. FYI, I am using RHEL 7

Below are the logs from the script:

```
[INFO]          File created.

[INFO]          Giving root permissions

[STATUS]                Writing contents on the file.

[STATUS]                Content written.
```

Thanks

Comment: cat command is so confusing, does it generates any output into file ?

Comment: nope. the 'touch' command itself is not creating the file

Comment: same script is working on my machine . So might be related some specific to your environment. add these lines `echo $?` and `echo $RESPONSE_FILE`  after lines `touch $RESPONSE_FILE` just see if there any errors after the execution of those commands

Comment: I found out what was the issue after lots of debugging. The issue was, when I was installing the RPM package, it was deleting this file. So what I did was I invoked this function after installing the RPM package and it worked!!